# Store and display the debug information in a custom DB table, while running the botcomposer bots using directline

Tags: azure, botframework, direct-line-botframework

We are creating bots using "Bot composer" and running those bots in Azure. we want to store the debug information for these bots in our custom DB tables.
Is there any way we can get the debug information that is provided in the "Bot emulator".
I was searching in Microsoft documentation, the closest I found is this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-testing-debugging?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

But even this does not talk much about my problem at hand. Can some point me in a direction where I can find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use [Inspection Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-inspection-middleware?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) in your Composer bot, you can simply do that by enabling `"UseInspectionMiddleware": true` in the bot settings.

If you would like to do anything other than that (i.e. use your own storage for debug info), you *must* customize the bot runtime. You will need to [extract and customize the runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-add-custom-action#export-runtime) to accomplish your goal. There is no documentation or steps on how to do this unique and specific task.